# Halloween Themed Outfits

Tags: fallout-shelter

My intrepid dwellers have brought back some skeleton costumes from their trips to the wasteland which they are now showing off to their comrades in my Halloween decorated barracks.

I am going to make a wild guess here and assume that these decorations will be gone again on or about the 1st of November. My question is - what happens to these skeleton outfits?

I presume this sort of seasonal decor has been used before (I've only been playing for about a month), so I am asking based on previous experiences.

Comment: The game is only a few months old and seasonal outfits have only started showing up recently. I've collected a Santa suit so it doesn't seem that the these outfits are time limited, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Whelp, guess I'm going to have to check on my vault again for the first time in weeks...

Comment: fyi there's also a ghost outfit, don't know if any more exist

Comment: I had the Santa Outfit - I figured that was just a rarity, rather than anything specifically Christmas themed (I also watched Die Hard last night, just at random).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These will be permanent items for one simple reason:

You can get them from a lunchbox, when you purchase a lunchbox using real money you are told you will receive a set amount of items, to later remove these would be both highly unfair and also possibly prohibited on the companies side by law or/and regulations.

Answer (score 2):

Based on how other games have acted on these sort of special event items (using Clash of Clans as an example) whatever holiday items you retrieve will be yours to keep, even after the event is over. You just won't be able to gather them after said event ends.

As I found on [the forums](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1541178-ghost-customs-available-in-lunchboxes/) they can also be found in lunch boxes.